# Are there any built-in methods for undefined data type in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, undefined

Asking this question I want to evaluate the following statement true or false:
"There are methods built-in to every data type in JavaScript"
As undefined in data type in JavaScript. I try to find any build-in method for an "undefined" but it appears that it's an only primitive type that does not have one. Or there are some?

```
let undef = void 0; 
console.log(undef.anyPotentialBuildInMethod());
```

Does any "anyPotentialBuildInMethod()" exists?

Comment: `== undefined` or `=== undefined` it's not clear what your expecting here?

Comment: OP wants to know if `undefined` has methods, can you call something on `undefined`.

Comment: In that case, No, it's undefined, it doesn't exist. Undefined is essentially a route literal with no methods or properties.

Comment: I'd suggest you read the [docs on undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)

Comment: Trying to access a property of `undefined` always gets an error.

Answer (score 2):

Methods are functions that are properties of objects.

Trying to read *any* property of `undefined` throws an exception.

`undefined` has no built-in methods and cannot be assigned any.

```js
const foo = undefined;

console.log(foo.sampleMethod);
```

Comment: *cannot be assigned any* you could override the `undefined` prototype I think? Not that this would be a good idea but I think it would be possible?

Comment: ah it seems you could do this (kinda) but now your can't. [In modern browsers (JavaScript 1.8.5 / Firefox 4+), undefined is a non-configurable, non-writable property, per the ECMAScript 5 specification. (Even when this is not the case, avoid overriding it.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined#description)

Answer (score 2):

While it might appear so, not everything in Javascript is an object. Primitive values (like `"foo"`, `12.34`, `undefined` etc) are not objects and cannot have methods or properties. However, Javascript hides that fact by dynamically boxing (or "coercing") primitive values into objects when you access their properties. So when you do

```
 x = "foo".length
```

what actually happens is

```
 1. temp = new String("foo")  // dynamically coerce a primitive value into an object
 2. x = temp.length           // get a property of that object
 3. destroy temp              // delete a temporary object
```

(Of course, Javascript engines don't actually allocate and then discard these temporary objects, this is just an algorithm defined by the standard, see (1) below).

Two primitive values: `null` and `undefined` are exception of this rule: any attempt to coerce them results in a `TypeError`. So when you do

```
  x = undefined.something
```

Javascript tries to create a temporary object like in the step 1 above and fails.

The bottom line: `null` and `undefined` cannot have properties, because they are primitive values and cannot be converted to objects.

References:

1. https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-getvalue
2. https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-evaluate-property-access-with-identifier-key
3. https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-requireobjectcoercible

Answer (score 1):

No, property access on *undefined* always throws a `TypeError` in a standards-compliant engine.

From [ECMA-262, 11th Ed., §12.3.2.1](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-property-accessors-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> *MemberExpression* : *MemberExpression* **[** *Expression* **]**
>
> […]
>
> 4. Return ? EvaluatePropertyAccessWithExpressionKey(*baseValue*, *Expression*, *strict*).
>
> […]
>
> *MemberExpression* : *MemberExpression* . *IdentifierName*
>
> […]
>
> 4. Return ? EvaluatePropertyAccessWithIdentifierKey(*baseValue*, *IdentifierName*, *strict*).

In both [§12.3.3](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-evaluate-property-access-with-expression-key) and [§12.3.4](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-evaluate-property-access-with-identifier-key) have:

> Let *bv* be ? RequireObjectCoercible(*baseValue*).

And in [§7.2.1](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-requireobjectcoercible) we have:

> The abstract operation RequireObjectCoercible throws an error if *argument* is a value that cannot be converted to an Object using ToObject. It is defined by Table 15:
>
> **Table 15: RequireObjectCoercible Results**
>
> | Argument Type | Result |
> | --- | --- |
> | Undefined | Throw a **TypeError** exception. |
> | Null | Throw a **TypeError** exception. |

The only thing that can possibly be considered an exception is the `document.all` object, which compares loosely-equal (`==` not `===`) to both undefined and `null`, and returns `'undefined'` when passed to the `typeof` operator, but actually has properties. This is specified in [§B.3.7](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-IsHTMLDDA-internal-slot); before the 9th edition of the standard, it was actually contrary to the specification.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the reason why you are asking this, but, to let you understand better, what you are trying to do is like trying (but not the same) to find an 'x' value so that (0 * x) != 0; 0 is 0 and whethever you use as 'x' you got 0.
And 'undefined' var in javascript is nothing. This is because 'var' doesn't have a type, it can be string, integer, object, function ecc

you can do

```
var test = "test";
console.log(test);
test = 1;
console.log(test);
```

and so on, and you'll get no error. var are evauated at execution time, and and undefined var is simply a pointer to nothing so you can't have a function or a property in that